# Need a unique convergence (UC) space's Alexandrov extension be a UC space?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, compactness, examples-counterexamples

**Background**

Say a topological space $X$ is

- a *unique convergence* (UC) space iff every sequence of points of $X$ converges to at most one point of $X$;
- a *unique convergent clustering* (UCC) space iff every convergent sequence of points of $X$ has a unique cluster point;
- a *KC space* iff compact subsets of $X$ are closed.

I've been able to show that Hausdorff $\implies$ KC $\implies$ UCC $\implies$ UC $\implies$ $T_1,$ and that a first-countable UC space is UCC.

Given a space $X$, we define the *Alexandrov extension* of a space $X$--which I denote $X_\alpha$--by adjoining a point $\infty$ to $X$, and making the neighborhoods of $\infty$ those subsets of $X\cup\{\infty\}$ whose complements are closed compact subsets of $X$. It can be shown that $X_\alpha$ is always compact, $X$ an open subspace of $X_\alpha,$ and that $X$ is dense in $X_\alpha$ if and only if $X$ is non-compact.

It is trivial to show that $X$ is $T_1$ iff $X_\alpha$ is $T_1,$ since finite sets are immediately compact. I'm also aware that $X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff iff $X$ is Hausdorff and locally compact.

***Edit***: I also "proved" before posting the question that $X$ is KC iff $X_\alpha$ is KC, but this turns out not to be true. When $X$ is the Arens-Fort space, then $X$ is Hausdorff (so KC), but $X_\alpha$ is not even KC, as pointed out [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515119/need-a-unique-convergence-uc-spaces-alexandrov-extension-be-a-uc-space?noredirect=1#comment10304076_515119). To see why, note that every neighborhood of the "point at infinity" in $X_\alpha$ is cofinite, so every subset of $X_\alpha$ containing this point is compact. However, the set consisting of "even columns" of $X$ is not open in $X_\alpha$ and doesn't contain the "point at infinity," so its complement is a compact, non-closed subset of $X_\alpha.$ Thanks again to MW for bringing that lovely counterexample to my attention!

***Edit***: Another "proof" was that $X$ was UCC if and only if $X_\alpha$ was UCC, but again, the Arens-Fort space provides a counterexample (so is an even *stronger* counterexample to preservation of the KC property by Alexandrov extension), as pointed out [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515119/need-a-unique-convergence-uc-spaces-alexandrov-extension-be-a-uc-space?noredirect=1#comment10311473_515119) once again by MW.

---

It is readily the case that if $X_\alpha$ is a UC space, then so is $X$. However, I've been unable to prove or disprove that if $X$ is UC, then so is $X_\alpha$. I suspect that it isn't true in general, but I haven't found any counterexamples.

If it is true, how might one go about proving it?

If it is not true, can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: If it is frequently at $\infty$ then it cannot converge to a point in $X$. So we can restrict attention to the sequences in $X$ converging to $\alpha\in X$ and to $\infty$.

Comment: The usual term for what you’re calling a $UC$ space is $US$ *space*.

Comment: Is there any chance that the closure of the underlying set of a convergent sequence in a UC (or US, pace Brian) space _must_ be quasicompact?

Comment: @Daniel: That's a good question. I was able to prove it for UCC spaces, but not for UC spaces.

Comment: For UCC spaces, if $x_n \to x$, then $\overline{\{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}} = \{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{x\}$, unless I'm mistaken. So in a UC but not UCC space, we have convergent sequences where the right hand side set is not closed. And a UC but not UCC space can't be first-countable.

Comment: @Daniel: You are not mistaken. I forgot to mention that first-countable UC spaces are UCC. Thank you for bringing that up.

Comment: "I've been able to show that $X$ is P iff $X_\alpha$ is P, when P is KC, UCC, or T1."  I realize this is over a decade old but in case anyone refers to this question it might be worth noting that this is not true for KC.  The Arens-Fort space (https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000023 ), for example, is KC (even $T_2$), but its one point compactification (https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000165 ) is not KC.

Comment: @MW: Thank you for bringing that counterexample to my attention! Sadly, I can no longer find the work I did to prove those claims, so I can't identify my mistake(s). I will adjust the post in a moment!

Comment: @CameronBuie  Actually thinking about it more, I guess the Arens Fort space is also an example of a UCC space whose $1$-point compactification is not UCC. The Arens fort space is UCC since it is Hausdorff, but if $(x_n)$ is any enumeration of the compactification, then $x_n$ converges to the point at infinity (since it eventually leaves every compact subset of the Fort space), but also clusters at $(0,0)$, since every neighborhood of $(0,0)$ is infinite.  [deleted original version of this comment which was slightly inaccurate.]

Comment: @MW, I can't believe I didn't even consider that! After all, I made at least one mistake in one proof, why not another? Lol!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a counterexample.

Let $P=\beta\omega\setminus\omega$ be the set of free ultrafilters on $\omega$. Let $X=(\omega+1)\cup P$ be topologized by making $\omega+1$ an open subset of $X$ with its usual order topology and declaring $U\subseteq X$ a nbhd of $p\in P$ iff $p\in U$ and $U\cap\omega\in p$. The only non-trivial sequences in $X$ are those that converge to $\omega$, so $X$ is $US$, but $\langle n:n\in\omega\rangle$ clusters at each point of $P$ (and of course converges to $\omega$), so $X$ is not $UCC$. Note that $\omega$ is dense in $X$, which is not compact, so it’s not the case that the range of a convergent sequence in a $US$ space must have compact closure.

$P$ is an infinite closed, discrete subset of $K$, and $P\cap\operatorname{cl}A$ is infinite for each infinite $A\subseteq\omega$. (In fact $|P\cap\operatorname{cl}A|=|\beta\omega\setminus\omega|=2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ for each infinite $A\subseteq\omega$.) Thus, the only compact, closed subsets of $X$ are the finite sets, and if $q$ is the point at infinity in $X^*$, the sequence $\langle n:n\in\omega\rangle$ converges to both $\omega$ and $q$.

Comment: (+1) Interesting. I haven't done much with Stone-Cech compactifications. Correct me if I'm wrong, but we need some small amount of Choice to know that there is a free ultrafilter over $\omega$ at all, yes?

Comment: @Cameron: I’m not sure of the exact consistency strength of *there is a non-principal ultrafilter on* $\omega$; some digging around indicates that it’s independent of DC and does not imply that $\Bbb R$ is well-orderable. The (at least formally) stronger statement that every filter of sets can be extended to an ultrafilter is quite strong, being equivalent to the [Boolean prime ideal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_prime_ideal_theorem) and the Tikhonov product theorem for compact Hausdorff spaces. (The full Tikhonov theorem is of course equivalent to AC.)