# closure of compact subspace

Tags: general-topology, compactness

It is known that If $X$ is a Hausdorff space then every compact subspace of $X$ is closed. Hence closure of compact subspace of $X$ is also compact.

My question: 
is there any a $T_1$ space $X$ such that if $A$ is a compact subspace of $X$ then closure of $A$ is not compact?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a $T_1$ space, then every finite subset of $X$ is both compact and closed. However, it is still possible for $X$ to have an infinite compact subset whose closure is not compact; the set $X\setminus P$ in the space described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/515196/12042) is an example.

Comment: M.Scott: Why every finite subset of $X$ is closed?

Comment: @Jaxa: If $X$ is $T_1$, then $\{x\}$ is closed for each $x\in X$, and every union of finitely many closed sets is closed.

Comment: M.Scott: I do not understand why $X\setminus P$ in your example is compact. What is closure of $X\setminus P$?

Comment: @Jaxa: The closure of$X\setminus P$ is the whole space. $X\setminus P$ is the compact ordinal space $\omega+1$, which is homeomorphic to $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ with its usual topology.